# Unable to get the physical monitor handle on Windows 7 for color calibration

Tags: windows, winapi

I'm on Windows 7 and I'm trying to change the color balance from code. Specifically, I'm trying to change these [sliders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ns34U.png) that show on the color calibration wizard.
I'm assuming that the correct functions are [SetMonitorRedGreenOrBlueGain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/highlevelmonitorconfigurationapi/nf-highlevelmonitorconfigurationapi-setmonitorredgreenorbluegain) and [SetMonitorRedGreenOrBlueDrive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/highlevelmonitorconfigurationapi/nf-highlevelmonitorconfigurationapi-setmonitorredgreenorbluedrive).

Here is my minimal working example:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "dxva2.lib")
#include <windows.h>
#include <lowlevelmonitorconfigurationapi.h>
#include <physicalmonitorenumerationapi.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{   
    HWND hWnd = GetDesktopWindow();
    HMONITOR hMonitor = MonitorFromWindow(hWnd, MONITOR_DEFAULTTOPRIMARY);
    cout << "Monitor: " << hMonitor << endl;

    DWORD cPhysicalMonitors;
    BOOL bSuccess = GetNumberOfPhysicalMonitorsFromHMONITOR(hMonitor, &cPhysicalMonitors);
    cout << "GetNumber: " << bSuccess << ", number of physical monitors: " << cPhysicalMonitors << endl;

    LPPHYSICAL_MONITOR pPhysicalMonitors = (LPPHYSICAL_MONITOR)malloc(cPhysicalMonitors * sizeof(PHYSICAL_MONITOR));
    bSuccess = GetPhysicalMonitorsFromHMONITOR(hMonitor, cPhysicalMonitors, pPhysicalMonitors);
    cout << "GetPhysicalMonitor: " << bSuccess << endl
        << "Handle: " << pPhysicalMonitors[0].hPhysicalMonitor << endl
        << "Description: ";
    wcout << (WCHAR*)(pPhysicalMonitors[0].szPhysicalMonitorDescription);
    
    DestroyPhysicalMonitors(cPhysicalMonitors, pPhysicalMonitors);
    free(pPhysicalMonitors);    
    
}
```

The output is:

```
Monitor: 00010001
GetNumber: 1, number of physical monitors: 1
GetPhysicalMonitor: 1
Handle: 00000000
Description: Generic PnP Monitor
```

All the functions for brightness and color gains require `HANDLE hPhysicalMonitor` which is always `null` for my display (laptop screen). But, I know it must be possible to change the color balance since the color calibration window can do that.

What am I doing wrong?

### EDIT 1:

As mentioned in the comments, it seems that the `hPhysicalMonitor` is correct. My issue is that calling functions like `GetMonitorBrightness` returns `FALSE` with an error code of `ERROR_GRAPHICS_I2C_ERROR_TRANSMITTING_DATA` (An error occurred while transmitting data to the device on the I2C bus.)

### EDIT 2:

My monitor does support setting brightness and has 11 levels. Windows itself and some programs are able to adjust the brightness (the back-light of the monitor directly). So the issue must be software related.

Comment: I have the same behavior on Windows 10 (with 2 monitors, 1 physical per monitor). What makes you think NULL (0) is an invalid "handle"? When I call GetMonitorCapabilities(0, ...) it takes some times and returns TRUE, when I use a bogus handle it returns FALSE and GetLastError() => ERROR_GRAPHICS_INVALID_PHYSICAL_MONITOR_HANDLE.

Comment: @SimonMourier I assumed that because GetMonitorBrightness for example returns false. Now that you've mentioned it, I checked the last error after GetMonitorBrightness and it is `ERROR_GRAPHICS_I2C_ERROR_TRANSMITTING_DATA` (An error occurred while transmitting data to the device on the I2C bus.). I'll update the question...

Answer (score 0):

> My issue is that calling functions like GetMonitorBrightness returns
> FALSE with an error code of ERROR_GRAPHICS_I2C_ERROR_TRANSMITTING_DATA
> (An error occurred while transmitting data to the device on the I2C
> bus.)

`GetMonitorBrightness` works for me. I tested it on i.e desktop. Some similar cases point out that `GetMonitorBrightness` does not work on some laptops.

- [GetMonitorCapabilities returns false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44084021/getmonitorcapabilities-returns-false)
- [How to control system brightness using windows api ?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/WINDOWS/en-US/5437ddb8-af86-4cf0-8061-798e6601e08e/how-to-control-system-brightness-using-windows-api-?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues)

I think your laptop does not support DDC/CI.

> [GetMonitorCapabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/highlevelmonitorconfigurationapi/nf-highlevelmonitorconfigurationapi-getmonitorcapabilities#return-value)： The function fails if the monitor does not
> support DDC/CI.

You may first check if your laptop supports DDC/Cl.

Comment: If my display doesn't support DDC/CI, how does Windows change the brightness and RGB gains? And other programs are able to change them as well. So if not by this function in the winapi, then how? I did a quick debug on those programs and I see that they import the functions `GetNumberOfPhysicalMonitorsFromHMONITOR` and `Set/GetMonitorBrightness` from the dxva2 library. (P.S. My display is the one in HP 15 r215nk laptop.)

Comment: @RationalFragile `SetMonitorBrightness` allows you to change the brightness of an external monitor, refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47333195/change-brightness-using-wmi). Instead, you can use [WmiSetBrightness](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmicoreprov/wmisetbrightness-method-in-class-wmimonitorbrightnessmethods?redirectedfrom=MSDN) to realize. [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/799207/11128312) may useful to you.